# How to run GTK# (C#) on a Mac OSX

Tags: c#, windows, macos, xamarin, gtk#

I have a GTK# project that has been developed using C#, on Xamarin Studio, on Windows.

I can generate an .exe file for my application but I can't run this on a Mac. Is there a way for me to convert this .exe file to a .dmg / .app OR to run this .exe on a Mac without using Windows (Bootcamp)?

Note: WineBottler has not worked for my project.

Answer (score 0):

You should use macpack to package the application for execution on OS X. Take a look at the manual here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/macpack.1.html

Here's an excerpt from that page:

> macpack   is   a   tool   used  to  package  managed  assemblies 
>   (like  System.Windows.Forms or  Cocoa#)  that  require  gui 
>   availability  for deployment on Mac OS X.
>
> macpack  will  prepare  a  OS  X  compatible  bundle  from the
>   provided assembly and resources.  The bundle will include the
>   specified assembly as well as any of the provided resources (specified
>   with the -resource: switch).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mono installed on your Mac then the .exe compiled on Windows *should* run unless you've got a dependency on something that is specific to windows. Some Windows libraries have not been ported to Mono for Mac or Linux, and if you are using ILMerge (windows) or ILRepack (*nix) then you will also potentially run into issues.

You don't need to use MacPack to build an app file, you can do it manually fairly simply as long as Mono is installed on your target Mac machine. There is a structure to an .app package folder which you can build manually.

Let me know if you need any more help, Cheers, M.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything special, provided both Gtk# and mono are installed. That said, there are not ports for many 32bits libraries, so you need to specify the architecture to use.

```
$ mono --arch:32 program.exe
```

Refer to this document:
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/